# Passing a member function as a function arg?

Tags: python, sqlite, select, functional-programming, pysqlite

I've written a very simple select function for SQLite, but I'm confused at how to pass a member function... e.g.: `.fetchone()`, `.fetchmany()`.

```py
def select(cursor, select="*", table="reuters", fetch=".fetchone()", tologfile=False, logfile=""):
    if tologfile:
        logfile = open(logfile, 'w')
        logfile.write(str(cursor.execute("select * from ?;".replace('?',table).replace("select * ", "select "+select)).fetchone()))
        logfile.close()
    else: return str(cursor.execute("select * from ?;".replace('?',table).replace("select * ", "select "+select)).fetchone())
```

**How do I pass this member function as an arg?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, got it to work:

```py
import sqlite3

def select(self, attr="*", table="reuters", fetch=None, num=None, tologfile=False, logfile=""):
    if fetch is None:
        fetch=self.fetchone
    output=self.execute("select * from ?;".replace('?',table).replace("select * ", ("select "+attr+' ')))

    output=fetch(num) if num else fetch()

    if tologfile:
        logfile = open(logfile, 'w')
        logfile.write(str(output))
        logfile.close()
    else: return output

if __name__ == '__main__':    
    connection = sqlite3.connect('winkwinknudgenudgesaynomore.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("drop table reuters;")
    cursor.execute("create table reuters (foo text, bar text);")
    connection.commit()
    print select(cursor)
    print select(cursor, 'bar')
    print select(cursor, 'bar', fetch=cursor.fetchmany, num=5)
    cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply pass `self.fetchone` to pass that function.

If you want it as a default value simply use `None` in the function definition and add

```
if whatever is None:
    whatever = self.fetchone
```

in the function itself.

If you want to call the method on another object but `self` keep passing it as a string and use this code (based on your `else` code since that one's shorter):

```
result = self.execute("select * from ?;".replace('?',table).replace("select * ", ("select "+attr)))
return str(getattr(result, whatever)())
```

Comment: Ah, you want to call that method on the object inside the query.. misunderstood your question

Comment: No worries, looking forward to reading your modified answer :)

Comment: Why not pass the unbound method (Class.method) around and call that, passing the desired instance as the first argument? No need to pass the name of the method around as a string.

Answer (score 2):

You could use getattr :

```
>>> class A:
...     def b(self):
...             print 'c'
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> getattr(a,'b')
<bound method A.b of <__main__.A instance at 0x7f2a24a85170>>
>>> getattr(a,'b')()
c
```

Answer (score 0):

A lambda could achieve this

```
class A:
  def test(self):
    print "hello world"

a = A()
func = (lambda: a.test())
func()
```

prints "hello world"

This technique can also be extended to deal with passing and transforming arguments

```
class B:
  def test(self, x):
    print x

b = B()
func = (lambda a, b : b.test(b))
func("garbage", "foo")
```

prints "foo"

Comment: Or, you could just use `func = a.test`. The lambda is unnecessary.